# How to convert JavaScript statement to PHP array

Tags: php, javascript

I read have one string like this:

```
$var = '[["tom",10,17.5],["af",13,["x",10,"y",12,"z",11]]]';
```

How should I convert this string to a PHP array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$json = "[["tom",10,17.5],["af",13,["x",10,"y",12,"z",11]]]";

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'tom'}; 
?>
```